# RoR roles management - rolify gem - use with resources of both UUID and Integer IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rolify

I saw the [FAQ on UUIDs](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/FAQ), but it changes the whole mechanism to use UUID.
How can I cope with some of my tables use UUID and some regular integer ID?

Thanks a log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  you should just add a migrations to the database tables that you want to use UUID on. `rails g migration add_uuid_to_sometablename` , and should be sufficient.

And if you need to index that particular column, you can say like

`add_index(:yourtablename, :uuid, unique: true)`

Comment: Thx! I will add a uuid field on all relevant models and it should work